# Is it possible to add decorators dynamically in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm developing a personal project in NestJS for learning purposes. Currently I'm integrating Swagger into it. So, let's suppose I want to show that a certain route may give as response the `UnauthorizedException`. I would naturally have to do this

```js
@ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ description: 'Unauthorized' })
@Get()
findAll() {
  return this.usersService.findAll();
}
```

But, I would like to add this decorator to all the routes that are not public. So, in an interceptor, I would get the current route handler and the `isPublic` metadata. From these, I would like to decide whether to add the decorator to the handler reference. But how would I do this, in case it is possible?

Right now, I imagine the interceptor to be something like this. Please disconsider the interceptor name, it is not final.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UnauthSwaggerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const handler = context.getHandler();

    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);

    if (!isPublic) {
      //  Apply Swagger decorator to handler
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

So as can be seen, I would first get a reference to the current handler, which is of type `Function`.

After that, obtain the `isPublic` metadata from the route using a `reflector`.

And then, verify if the route is not public in order to apply the decorator. I mark a route as public with the public decorator.

```js
export const IS_PUBLIC = 'isPublic';

export const Public = () => SetMetadata(IS_PUBLIC, true);
```

So, I would like to attach the aforementioned decorator for Unauthorized response, to this specific non-public handler. Would it be possible to do this? As it's not the function declaration, it's a reference that will be obtained during runtime. In positive case, then what would be the correct course of action?

I don't know if there is a way to directly apply the decorator to the function. Even because the decorator can only be applied in the context of a class, but I want to apply it only to controller methods. As I understand, the Swagger plugin for Nest does basically this, it adds decorators on the fly based on certain rules. This is also what I want to achieve, if possible.

Comment: Where does the `isPublic` metadata come from in the first palce?

Comment: Hello @JayMcDoniel, I have edited the question to explain this information a bit better. Hope it's clearer now. Even then, do you think this kind of information is relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to try and update the decorators bound during runtime. Decorators are there so that at the start of the server, certain actions can be taken or read during runtime. In the case of the swagger decorators, those all are read during server start up through the `SwaggerModule`'s `createDocument` method. Even if you were to change them at the time of request, you wouldn't modify the current swagger, and it wouldn't persist after a server restart.

Comment: Maybe the interceptor is not the best option, as I didn't use it much... But the intention would be to do this appending when application starts, not related to request-response lifecycle. So, unfortunately the only way would be to apply the decorator to every single route that is not public, you think?

Comment: Just a minor correction, as I'm not being able to update last comment. Probably would not be after application start, but after build, like the Swagger plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, there's no built-in for something like this with Nest. You could possibly use the `DiscoveryService` in your `main` and try to find all `@Controller()`s and then check each route of the controller, but I feel that's gonna end up being more work and maintenance than just adding the decorators yourself

Comment: I see, I didn't know about the existence of this service in Nest, the `DiscoveryService`. I will give it a look just to see how this implementation would be. Thanks a lot for the tip, even though you advised me in the opposite direction, haha. Thanks again, and best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

[A decorator is just a function that's called with the decoratee](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators) (though here we have what the TS manual calls a decorator factory):

```
function Decorator(s: string) {
  return (target: any) => {
    console.log("Decorating", target);
    target.foo = s;
    return target;
  };
}

// Decorator syntax
@Decorator("wibba wubba")
class SomeClass {}

// Call syntax
const OtherClass = Decorator("webbo wobbo")(class OtherClass {});

console.log((SomeClass as any).foo);
console.log((OtherClass as any).foo);
```

This prints out

```
"wibba wubba" 
"webbo wobbo"
```

as you'd imagine.

IOW,

```
@Injectable()
class Foo {}
```

is approximately equal to

```
const Foo = Injectable()(class Foo{});
```

and you can imagine a variable holding a function in `Injectable()`'s stead.